# Crash Project with 0 errors (AS)

Tags: kotlin, android-activity

The essence of the problem: after adding a certain code to MainActivity, the application crashes without displaying errors, probably some elements conflict with each other.
extension code: `ipadd = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.ipadd); WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(WIFI_SERVICE); ipadd.setText(Formatter.formatIpAddress(wifiManager.getConnectionInfo().getIpAddress()));`
main code:

```
package com.bruh.vpn
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.Menu
import com.google.android.material.snackbar.Snackbar
import com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
import androidx.navigation.findNavController
import androidx.navigation.ui.AppBarConfiguration
import androidx.navigation.ui.navigateUp
import androidx.navigation.ui.setupActionBarWithNavController
import androidx.navigation.ui.setupWithNavController
import androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import com.bruh.vpn.databinding.ActivityMainBinding
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private lateinit var appBarConfiguration: AppBarConfiguration
    private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)
        setSupportActionBar(binding.appBarMain.toolbar)
        binding.appBarMain.fab.setOnClickListener { view ->
            Snackbar.make(view, "Ping - *ms", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                .setAction("Action", null).show()
        }
        val drawerLayout: DrawerLayout = binding.drawerLayout
        val navView: NavigationView = binding.navView
        val navController = findNavController(R.id.nav_host_fragment_content_main)
        appBarConfiguration = AppBarConfiguration(
            setOf(
                R.id.nav_home, R.id.nav_gallery, R.id.nav_slideshow
            ), drawerLayout
        )
        setupActionBarWithNavController(navController, appBarConfiguration)
        navView.setupWithNavController(navController)
    }
    override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu): Boolean {

        menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu)
        return true
    }
    override fun onSupportNavigateUp(): Boolean {
        val navController = findNavController(R.id.nav_host_fragment_content_main)
        return navController.navigateUp(appBarConfiguration) || super.onSupportNavigateUp()

    }
}
```

Comment: There is always an error if your app crashes. Make sure you don't have a filter turned on in LogCat that might be hiding your error.

Comment: Unfortunately, the filters are not installed

Comment: Maybe take a screenshot of the LogCat panel, including showing all the buttons on the top and left side of it, so we can see for sure. I've been writing for Android for 12 years and have never seen a crash that did not show an error in the log. I'm not sure what else it could be.

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake, the error is really present, I recently started doing this and have not fully mastered everything yet. here is a screenshot   (https://i.stack.imgur.com/9DqWt.png)

Comment: Do you have multiple versions of your layout for different screen orientations? You may have missed including your TextView by its same name in one of the layouts.

Comment: I don't have mock-up versions for different screen resolutions

Comment: Sorry for the off-topic question, but could you help me create a textview that displays the user his current IP and the delay in ms. This is exactly what I was trying to do when I got the fatal error. here is an example of this implementation:  https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Iwa1.jpg